# PGrouting costs

Tags: sql, pgrouting, dijkstra, astar

Most algorithms have two functions:

- A normal one: like dijkstra()
- A `Cost-version`: like DijkstraCost()

I want the result of the `cost version`: A fast computation of the total seconds.
In mine edges table I have the following fields:

- `Seconds`: Time to walk
- `Score`:  More a 'road class'
- `Penalty`: Take the escalator above the stairs (which is not faster if you stand still)

The field I use in SQL for DijkstraCost(): `cost` = `Score` * `Penalty`

In many cases the costs are in seconds, but not here. 
So DijkstraCost() returns the real costs (in my case for every edge: score*penalty into an aggregate)

My question is :

**How do I get the total sum of seconds with a `Cost-version` like DijkstraCost()**

My SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraCost(
    'SELECT id,
    source,
    target,
    score* penalty  AS cost,
    score* penalty  AS reverse_cost,

    penalty,
    length,
    geom AS the_geom
    FROM network'
    ,20,30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `cost` of pgRouting is used for the cost function. In your case the cost is "score * penalty".

The `pgr_dijkstraCost()` function is mainly for convenience, for example when you request multiple origins/destinations at the same time but are just interested in the total cost. However, if the actual aggregated cost should be a different one than the one used for the cost function, then you need to use  `pg_dijkstra()` and join the shortest path result with your original table to use other attributes as costs.

Example:

```
SELECT dijkstra.*, network.my_cost, ST_AsText(network.the_geom)
  FROM pgr_dijkstra(<...>) AS dijkstra
  LEFT JOIN network
  ON (edge = gid) ORDER BY seq;
```

Comment: Okay, and if I am only interested in the 'score*cost' I aggregate that.
I just assumed that the dijkstraCost() function would be faster.

Comment: You could write your own function to use different costs for aggregation, and a good starting point might be this file, that defines the `dijkstraCost` "wrapper" functions: https://github.com/pgRouting/pgrouting/blob/master/sql/dijkstra/dijkstraCost.sql